# Como carregar ComboBox em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

Tenho 2 ComboBox: o 1º representa as províncias, o 2ª os municípios. Quando o usuário clicar no ComboBox 1 e selecionar uma província quero que os seus municípios apareçam no ComboBox 2.

Comment: esta usando asp.net web.forms ou asp.net mvc? A primeira coisa que precisa saber é como implementar o evento de selecionar um item do primeiro combobox, e nesse evento preenche o segundo combobox e assim por diante. abs

Comment: Isto é ASP.Net, WinForms ou outros coisa?Quando for fazer uma pergunta, procure dar o máximo de informações possíveis, colocar as *tags* adequadas, dar uma caprichada na formatação para que facilite todos entenderem o problema.

Answer (score 1):

usando banco de dados, crie um evento DropDown no combo que faça o seguinte::

```
//LIMPA OS ITENS DO COMBO
nomedoCombo.Items.Clear();

//CONECTA NO BANCO E RETORNA A CONEXÃO (DEVE TER SUA MANEIRA DE CONECTAR, ESSA É A MINHA)
ClassBancoDeDados Conn = new ClassBancoDeDados();


//PREPARA O SQL
String sSql = " SELECT campo FROM tabela order by campo";

MySqlDataReader DataReader = Conn.SqlQuery(sSql);
try
{
    if (DataReader.HasRows)
    {
       //se existem dados, serão adicionados no combobox
        while (DataReader.Read())
        {
            nomeDoCombo.Items.Add(DataReader.GetString(0));
        }
     }
}
catch
{
     return;
}
```

Gosto de colocar no dropdown pq sempre vai trazer atualizado

até a proxima